# Automatically clear Rstudio temp files when manually stopping background "job"

Tags: rstudio

When I manually stop a local background job (that is running a loop over many `rstan` analyses) on Rstudio, Rstudio/R treat the job as if it's failed (rather than purposely stopped), and I'm stuck with 10's of GB of files in my "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp" folder that I must manually remove. Is there some way to have Rstudio automatically remove these files only when a job is manually stopped (as opposed to failing)?

Comment: This is a tech support issue: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us